storage class for variables template at global/named namespace scope
While trying to get my thoughts straight about storage class, I wrote the following snippet:
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> T pi;
template<> extern int pi<int>;

int main() {
    std::cout << pi<int> << '\n';
}

LIVE
gcc gives me a compilation error explicit template specialization cannot have a storage class that I can't relate with, for instance, cppreference storage class specifiers.
clang compiles but gives me a "undefined reference" error on link which disappear if I initialize the variable with: template<> extern int pi<int>{3};
But it gives me a warning about initializing an extern variable (which would be, if I get it right, a plain error with a non-template variable)
msvc compiles and links without blinking an eye.
Which compiler is correct (if any) and why?
NB in real code I would have made the specialization inline constexpr

extern template is an explicit template instantiation, i am not sure whether template<> extern is defined or not.

@AhmedAEK explicit template instantiation does not seem to apply to variable template

it does, but only msvc allows you to initialize it ... for a reason that's beyond me ... most likely compiler bug in gcc/clang

but this works, so it is 100% compiler bug in clang/gcc for not accepting an explicit template variable instantiation initialization.

Explicit specializations do not introduce names. They share their name with the primary template and thus have the same linkage as their primary template. So it doesn't make sense to apply extern or static to it (and in fact doing so is not allowed). inline has a meaning distinct from deciding linkage, although it sometimes does affect linkage as well. So inline is allowed here and does make sense.

but then you run into another gcc/clang explicit template instantiation initialization bug ... so the whole thing is random, and you just need to test for something that isn't bugged in all the compilers you intend to use

@AhmedAEK You're right. cppreference only pointed me to class and function explicit instanciation but the standard 13.9.2.1 indeed mentioned explicit instantiation for variable template. Sorry

@AhmedAEK these examples are most probably IFNDR

@Dmitry nothing is wrong with them, they are not specializing the template after it is used, they are all correct use of explicit template instantiation this is just how the file would look like after the preprocessor is done when you use explicit template instantiation and the #include are pasted into the file, normally they would be split into header and .cpp file so you won't see them this close to one another.

@AhmedAEK In this example, you instantiate s and then forbid instantiation of s, this is clearly UB

@Dmitry specialization is not instantiation, it first specializes the template, but doesn't instantiate it, the line int s<int>::pi = 3; does the instantiation, and no other translation unit is allowed to instantiate it because of the extern above it, normally the extern would be in the header, and the instantiation would be in the .cpp file

@AhmedAEK cppreference says "This can be used to reduce compilation times by explicitly declaring a template instantiation in all but one of the source files using it, and explicitly defining it in the remaining file." Your example just doesn't follow this rule. Your second example is actually similar. explicit template forbids instantiation in the current TU, but you do instantiate the template there.

@Dmitry the problem here is not that they don't allow you to instantiate it, the problem is that they allow you to instantiate it, they only don't allow you to initialize it, you are only allowed to default-initialize it, they all agree that you can declare a template extern then instantiate it in the same TU (which is how everyone uses it), the problem here is that the instantiation syntax is recognized as instantiation, but the initialization syntax is not recognized as initialization..

GCC's diagnostic is correct, as per [temp.expl.spec]/2:

An explicit specialization shall not use a storage-class-specifier other than thread_local.


Thx. I think that the answer could be a bit more detailed, inspiring from @AhmedAEK comment. The syntax is indeed a specialization and your answer regarding gcc is accurate. It seems, on the other hand, that clang erroneously parse the code as an extern template declaration, leading to its behavior. I can't explain msvc behavior, except that it's wrong...
